# (Large or big) inheritance

Tags: word-usage, difference, adjectives

I was wondering whether we can swap "large" and "big" in the following example without sounding odd:

> - When her husband died, she came into a **large** inheritance.

I think they both are correct here, but I have no idea if using "big" rather than "large" is an idiomatic combin ation here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big inheritance is grammatically correct but is not the habitual collocation.  [image]

Comment: Large is more formal.

Comment: I'd say [***substantial*** is "more formal".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+large+inheritance%2Ca+big+inheritance%2Ca+substantial+inheritance&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20large%20inheritance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20big%20inheritance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20substantial%20inheritance%3B%2Cc0) It's not so common as ***large***, but it's ***way*** more common than ***big***.